# How to handle onBackPressed in KeyguardManager

Tags: android, keyguard

I want to perform some action on click of back button of `KeyguardManager.exitKeyguardSecurely()` method. My purpose is to finish the activity from which the `KeyguardManager` security `Activity` is Opened .

In the Home `Activity` of my app I have opened security pattern screen using below code.

```
 KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
        keyguardManager.exitKeyguardSecurely(new KeyguardManager.OnKeyguardExitResult() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyguardExitResult(boolean success) {
                if (success) {

                }
            }
        });
        startActivity(intent);
```

And I want to finish the Home `Activity` on click of the back button of the phone,How can I achieve it ? 
Thank you

Comment: try to write finish() after startActivity and it will close your current HomeActivity.

Comment: I want to know weather do we have control over the back button of the Systems security screen of KeyguardManager ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

@Override

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // put action here
    super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
    // you could add 'finish()' to finish your current activity
}
```